# How to find a function/operator that satisfies the following conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

I'm looking for a function that satisfies :

 1) Symmetric: $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$

 2) Associative: $f(f(x,y), z) = f(x,f(y,z))$

 3) $f(x,x) = 0$

 4) it would be nice if $f(x,0) = x$, or at least that $g(x) = f(x,0)$ is a function which have inverse function.

if we assume $x,y \in N$ we can use the bitwise xor operator for example. But I wonder how to find this function ? is there any analytical method of doing this ? how can we find another function in $N$ or in $R$ that satisfies the those conditions ?

Comment: What do you want for the domain and range? For example, multiplication on a group with one element satisfies all of your conditions

Comment: let's assume the domain and range is $N$ or $R$, but can you please explain in more detail what do you mean by multiplication on a group with one element ?

Comment: For a group with one element $\{0\}$, having multiplication $*$, we have $0*0=0$, and $(0*0)*0=0*(0*0)=0$.

Comment: well, I've edited my question to add 4th condition which won't allow the trivial $f(x,y)=0$ for example.

Comment: Yes it will, if there's only one element in the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions have actually been completely classified. Your example of bitwise XOR is really the *only* example; all that charges is the number of bits (which can be infinite). A particular example may not look at all similar to this but nevertheless it will be isomorphic.

A set with this operation is a vector space over the field of integers mod 2, which consists of the elements $0,1$ with $1+1=0$. This means we can multiply an element of the set by a scalar (an integer mod 2) and it will behave properly, which tells us that $f(x,x)=0$, and the operation (which is seen as addition) is commutative and associative.

Note that this requires all four conditions. Without condition $4$ this isn't true anymore.

Comment: interesting. so I guess there is no operation over the field of real numbers ? sort of XOR extension ?  where can I read more about the classification of those functions ?

Comment: @d_e well you can actually put an operation like this on the power set of any set; the operation is symmetric difference. But even if it's the power set of the real numbers, that's not really over the field of real numbers. This topic is at the intersection of abstract algebra and linear algebra. You would only find it in abstract linear algebra textbooks (geared towards math majors), but every intro abstract algebra book covers fields of integers modulo a prime. You can probably find some notes online in abstract linear algebra.

Comment: thanks, so I guess there is not such a function in $R$ ?

Comment: @d_e there is but it's not really interesting. It exists simply because of its cardinality, but it doesn't really interact with the structure.